# mvc3 jquery class selector not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model

I am having an issue with Jquery and MVC3 I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with model binding, I am basically trying to load a dropdownlist to my page using jquery **now this example below works**...

```
  @model way.Models.servicer

  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.adtype, new SelectList(
              new List<Object>{  
                    new { Text = " ", Value = " "},
                   new { Text = "Financial", Value = "Financial"}}, "Value", "Text"), new {@class="mylist" }) 


<script>
  $(".mylist").change(function () {
      if ($(this).val() == "Financial") {
          $("#miness").load('/Listings/service .credit');
      }

  });
</script>
```

which then loads this dropdownlist, the model servicer is

```
@model way.Models.servicer

 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.keyword, new SelectList(
              new List<Object>{  
                    new { Text = "Book-keeping", Value = "Book-keeping"},
                   new { Text = "Credit Repair", Value = "Credit Repair"}}, "Value", "Text"), new {@class="credit" })
```

The example above works now I basically use the same steps this model below but this example **does not work**

```
    @model way.Models.article_detail

 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.profile.groups, new SelectList(
              new List<Object>{  
                  new { Text = " ", Value = " "},
            new { Text = "Computer", Value = "Computer"}}, "Value", "Text"), new {@class="bty"})

       <script>
          $(".bty").change(function () {

           if ($(this).val() == "Computer") {
               $("#miness").load('/Listings/ding .computer');
           }

       });
   </script>
```

which then suppose to load this dropdownlist

```
    @model way.Models.article_detail

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.profile.role, new SelectList(new List<Object>{ 
                                new { Text = "windows", Value = "windows"},new { Text = "mac", Value = "mac"}}, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "computer" })
```

I do not get why 1 works and the other one does not. There is 1 small difference the 2nd example has 2 models in 1 view thus the **model.profile.role** maybe somehow the 2 models in 1 view is throwing things off but I am referencing the class so I do not know what's happening any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading your dropdown through jquery ajax if yes then you have to rebind the jquery event to the control because jquery binding works only if dom element is loaded before jquery.